# Azure - delete a load balancer used by a AKS cluster virtual machine scale set

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-cli, azure-vm-scale-set

On my Azure infrastructure I need to remove LoadBalancer for Kubernetes cluster when I restart it (long story why, but without it server can't be started)

Using CLI this job will look like this code:

```
az vmss update
   --resource-group MyResourceGroup
   --name MyVMSS
   --remove virtualMachineProfile.networkProfile.networkInterfaceConfigurations[0].ipConfigurations[0].loadBalancerBackendAddressPools
az vmss update-instances 
   --instance-ids "*" 
   --resource-group MyResourceGroup
   --name MyVMSS
```

And remove LoadBalancer afterwards

But from Azure Automation account I'm able to use either PowerShell or Azure API requests

Tried with Azure API to set `loadBalancerBackendAddressPools` to empty/null value, but it makes full network interface of VMSS broken

Does anyone knows a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to remove the load balancer (LB) created during your AKS cluster provision?
if yes, please don't. That LB is managed by AKS backend and is not supposed to be changed manually. removing it will break your AKS cluster.
It can only be changed via `az aks` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest) if there is an option for it (and there is not much available).
If I get your question wrong, just ignore what I just said.

Comment: Question is more about a way how to do step described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/update-load-balancer-with-vm-scale-set#delete-a-load-balancer-used-by-a-virtual-machine-scale-set in Powershell or Azure API